# Scrape actives from a group

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Hey so I have this skript which was scraping all the actives (7 days or last seen recently) from a group and put them on a csv, it has been working but these days it only writes my name on the csv. Any idea on how to fix it?

````
all_participants = []
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)

print('Saving In file...')
with open("Actives.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(['sr. no.','username','user id','name','group', 'group id','last seen'])
    i = 0
    for user in all_participants:

        accept=True
        try:
            lastDate=user.status.was_online
            num_months = (datetime.now().year - lastDate.year) * 12 + (datetime.now().month - lastDate.month)
            if(num_months>1):
                accept=False
        except:
            continue

        if (accept):
            i += 1
            if user.username:
                username= user.username
            else:
                username= ""
            if user.first_name:
                first_name= user.first_name
            else:
                first_name= ""
            if user.last_name:
                last_name= user.last_name
            else:
                last_name= ""
            name= (first_name + ' ' + last_name).strip()
            writer.writerow([i,username,user.id,name,target_group.title, target_group.id,user.status])

print('Members scraped successfully.')```
````

Comment: It is difficult to know without data and a bit more information.  You should run this through a debugger in your IDE.  Set breakpoints and monitor.  If you don't have an IDE, Spyder is a simple IDE that is easy to learn.  PyCharm is a bit more robust with a steeper learning curve.  -- If I had to guess, your try/except block is always sending you to continue.  If that is the case, the "continue" statement sends you to the next iteration of the for loop, skipping the "if (accept):" block.